# geospatial DQL in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, geospatial, dql

I've installed [creof's Doctrine2-Spatial](https://github.com/creof/doctrine2-spatial) to use geospatial functions in doctrine, but I'm having trouble in creating a proper DQL.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
$queryBuilder->andWhere("ST_CONTAINS((select area from BundleA:EntityA where id = (select area_id from BundleB:EntityB where id = 5)), alias.geoPoint");
```

`BundleA:EntityA` has and id and area (polygon type)

`BundleB:EntityB` has an area_id which references id from `BundleA:EntityA`

`alias.geoPoint` is where a `point` (lat,lng) is stored

The error I receive is this:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col xxx: Error: Expected Literal, got 'select'"
```

I also tried something like:

```
$queryBuilder->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
    sprintf("ST_Contains((select area from BundleA:EntityA where id = (select area_id from BundleB:EntityB where id = 5), alias.geoPoint)"),
    $queryBuilder->expr()->literal(true)
));
```

But the same error occurs

Comment: possibly a simple problem about parentheses, can you try this: `$queryBuilder->andWhere("
 ST_CONTAINS(
  select a.area from BundleA:EntityA a where a.id = (select b.area_id from BundleB:EntityB b where b.id = 5)
  , alias.geoPoint)
");`

Comment: @Matteo Nop, still the same